# Changing indexes in string

Tags: c#, string

I wonder how i can make my program change numbers in a string which is inside the loop.
This is how my program looks like now, and the thing I want to change is string index, so every time, user inputs a new number, program asks him for another one like that:
Enter number #1:
Enter number #2:
Enter number #3: etc.

```
        int[] numbers = new int[1000];
        int counter;

        for(counter = 0; counter < numbers.Length; counter++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter Number ");

            string line = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (line)) {
                Console.WriteLine ("No numbers entered, please input some numbers");
                continue;
            }


            if(line == "stop")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                int.TryParse(line, out numbers[counter]);
            }
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine (string.Format("Enter Number#{0} ", counter+1));

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Enter number #{0}:", counter + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

just change line like this

```
int[] numbers = new int[1000];
    int counter;
        for(counter = 0; counter < numbers.Length; counter++)
        {
                Console.WriteLine (string.Format("Enter Number {0}: ",Counter+1));




            string line = Console.ReadLine();




            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (line)) {
                Console.WriteLine ("No numbers entered, please input some numbers");
                continue;
            }








            if(line == "stop")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                int.TryParse(line, out numbers[counter]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a string that is "Enter number #" + counter and out it